# How to display part of webpage on mobile phone?

Tags: html, css

I have a website which is working well on PC. Now I want it can be displayed on mobile phone like following:

1. Align left and display only 1024px from left.
2. The rest part:
   1) The rest part can be kept and user just only need to drag to see the content. This will be the best, and if this happen, it is only need to do some zoom in and out work. But I found it is really difficult to make it working properly on all mobile web browsers.

   2) Do not display the rest of part. This is also an acceptable option.

Thank you very much if you can give any advice.

Comment: why don't you want to make your website responsive?

Comment: For responsive design you use css media queries. There you can hide and show info based on "browser width". If you do a google search you will get tons of info and examples of it. There are already done frameworks for this and one being http://getbootstrap.com/css/.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend converting your website in to using [**Bootstrap**](http://getbootstrap.com/). It makes it responsive, so you should not have any trouble with the mobile view at any point.

From the developers view the Bootstrap offers many and much more to the website creation. No need to hazzle around with the percentages or make entire new pages for mobile phones, one page does it all.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do almost whatever you want if you adjust your website to be responsive to different screen sizes and user agents. Media queries will help you adapt your website greatly to different screen sizes, media types and orientation